# Does the sentence "I won't excuse you" make sense?

Tags: grammar

Example. I won't forgive you.

I know this sentence makes sense. Then, do you say, "I won't excuse you"?

Semantically, these are almost the same, maybe. But, how about the usage? Do you use the verb "excuse" like this?  The phrase like "excuse somebody for doing something " is the way you use it, isn't it?

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionary; a2](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/excuse):m, A2
used to say sorry for something you have done by accident:
_Did I take your seat? Do excuse me._ // Often, a for-phrase is given to explain the perceived malpractices, but this is not mandatory.  And certainly, 'I won't excuse you' can be very confrontational (even if judged deserved) and is correspondingly rare.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This has nothing to do with current politics or wars.

I just remembered [this scene from Transporter 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64hqMUo4ROY).

> Valentina: I'm not Russian. I'm Ukrainian.
> Frank: Excuse me.
> Valentina: Not excused.

To excuse someone is to "seek to lessen the blame attaching to (a fault or offence); try to justify". So when you don't excuse someone, you are simply not lessening the blame.

Comment: How idiomatic is "you are not excused" without a from- or by-string?